# How to turn off select variables in lists by the head letter of the name in R

Tags: r, list

say I have a list created by

`x = list(tau = 3, ga = rep(0,3))`

However, now I want to test if a variable `t` or `g` is contained in `x`, so I use
`is.null(x$t)`

of course it returns to `FALSE` because `x$t = 3`. How can I turn off this behavior?

update:

OK, my aim is to identify if there a variable `g` is contained, because in my code `g` and `ga` both are meaning full and are the true names of the variables. That is, if or not `g` is contained represents two different scenarios, and I am not asking a way to cleverly choose variables from `x`.

my current way is to use `x[['g']]` and this returns what I want. I am thinking if I can turn off this global environment behavior?

Comment: how to turn off this "partial dollar match" behavior, I think this should be the key.

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer for the correct response. The first part answers your question header, the edit answers your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out something like:

```
x = list(tau = 3, ga = rep(0,3))

x[-which(substr(names(x),1,1)== "t")]
```

which should only return `$ga`.

**EDIT**

If you want to search names without autocomplete on a list, avoid using `$t` and instead use `[["t"]]`.

In your example you would want `is.null(x[["t"]])` which is TRUE.

Comment: If this has helped you and answered you question please mark this question as answered with the check mark on the left.

Comment: Let's see if someone answers if we can turn such partial matching off in `option`, and if not, yours are the marked one.

Comment: Here is a post from a long time ago saying it was not possible then. https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2004-February/028962.html. I do know that the `$` is an operator so there is code to it. But I highly recommend you use double square brackets instead.